# Is range tree widely used in spacial search problems?

Tags: data-structures, computational-geometry, kdtree, range-tree

I am looking for some data structures for range searching. I think *range trees* offer a good time complexity (but with some storage requirements).

However, it seems to me that other data structures, like *KD-trees*, are more discussed and recommended than *range trees*. Is this true? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that it is because kd-trees can straightforwardly be extended to contains objects other than points. This gives it many applications in e.g. virtual worlds, where we want quick querying of triangles. Similar extensions of range trees are not straightforward, and in fact I've never seen any.

To give a quick recap: a kd-tree can preprocess a set of n points in d-space in O(n log n) time into a structure using O(n) space, such that any d-dimensional range query can be answered in O(n<sup>1-1/d</sup> + k) time, where k is the number of answers. A range trees takes O(n log<sup>d-1</sup>n) time to preprocess, takes O(n log<sup>d-1</sup>n) space, and can answer range queries in O(log<sup>d-1</sup>n + k) time.

The query time for a range tree is obviously a lot better than that of a kd-tree, if we're talking about 2- or 3-dimensional space. However, the kd-tree has several advantages. First of all, it always requires only linear storage. Secondly, it is always constructed in O(n log n) time. Third, if the dimensionality is very high, it will outperform a range tree unless your points sets are very large (although arguably, at this point a linear search will be almost as fast as a kd-tree).

I think another important point is that kd-trees are more well known by people than range trees. I'd never heard of a range tree before taking a course in computational geometry, but I'd heard of and worked with kd-trees before (albeit in a computer graphics setting).

EDIT: You ask what is a better data structure for 2D or 3D fixed radius search when you have millions of points. I really can't tell you! I'd be inclined to say a range tree will be faster if you perform many queries, but for 3D the construction will be slower by a factor of O(log n), and memory use may become an issue before speed does. I'd recommend integrating good implementations of both structures and simply testing what does a better job for your particular requirements.

Comment: So what do you think is a better data structure if I want to do 2D or 3D fixed radius search for particle simulation where there are millions of points and the search range is rather smaller compared to the whole space? should I use range tree or are there better alternatives?

Comment: basically, I want to perform one query for every of the particles

Comment: @Alaya In that case you may be looking for something called the all nearest neighbours search.

Comment: I googled those data structures and algorithms, but found that they seemed to be proposed to solve the nearest neighbor problem. 
so how should I use them to solve fixed-radius neighbor search, do I need to do kth-nearest-neighbor search over and over again 
until I found the kth neighbor is beyond the search radius? I didn't try that, but I suppose that would cause a lot of waste.

Comment: @Alaya considering the complexity is O(mn log n), with m the number of neighbours, that is most likely the case. The wikipedia page for the [fixed-radius near neighbours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-radius_near_neighbors) also offers some references.

Answer (score 0):

For your needs (particle simulation in 2D or 3D), you want a data structure capable of all nearest neighbor queries. The cover tree is a data structure that is best suited for this task. I came across it while computing the nearest neighbors for kernel density estimation. This [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree) explains the basic definition of the tree, and [John Langford's page](http://hunch.net/~jl/projects/cover_tree/cover_tree.html) has a link to a C++ implementation.

The running time of a single query is O(c^12*logn), where c is the expansion constant of the dataset. This is an upper bound - in practice, the data structure performs faster than others. [This paper](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~isbell/reading/papers/cover-tree-icml.pdf) shows that the running time of batch processing of all nearest neighbors (for all the data points), as needed for a particle simulation, is O(c^16*n), and this theoretical linear bound is also practical for your need. Construction time is O(nlogn) and storage is O(n).

Comment: If I want to search all neighbors within a fixed radius instead of searching the nearest neighbor, is cover tree still a practical option?

Comment: definitely - that's exactly what it's aimed at